# Search PC List | If Service is Running, Copy PC Name to File

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface

I have the below batch file, which will take a list of server names, "servers.txt" and plug the individual names into the service control command.

```
for /f %%a in (servers.txt) do (
sc \\%%a query "service_name"
)
```

This will tell me simply if the service is running or not. With a list of some 900+ servers, what i want to accomplish is, if the service is found running on a particular server, append that servername to a file.

something like:

```
for /f %%a in (servers.txt) do (
sc \\%%a query "service_name" | findstr /i "Running" %%a >> "running.txt"
)
```

I've tried using this with and without if statements, goto, but clearly my syntax is wrong.

Thanks

/bt

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (servers.txt) do (
sc \\%%a query "service_name" 2>&1 | findstr /i "Running" >nul 2>&1 && echo %%a 
)>>running.txt
```

Comment: For some reason, the above is not writing to txt file. it's just printing all of the above in the command line. i've tried this as well:

`for /f %%a in (servers.txt) do (
sc \\%%a query "service_name" | findstr /i "Running" %%a >nul 2>&1 && echo %%a *>>* "running.txt"
)`

Comment: @btgream yees.I forgot the redirection.Is it working with the `>>` ?

Comment: strangely getting the exact same results.

Comment: still not writing to text file for some reason. CLI Output: (sc \\SERVERNAME query "service_name" | findstr /i "Running" SERVERNAME >nul 2>&1 && echo SERVERNAME ) 1>>running.txt very bizarre.

Comment: do you replace the "service_name"  with your own service?

Comment: yes of course, was forgetting a couple of times, but i will test this new batch out now..

Comment: for some reason, it's still doing the same thing. it creates the output text file, but doesn't write anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic /node:"@c:\servers.txt" service where "name='wudfsvc'" get name, started, status /format:hform > Services.html
```

Comment: wmic /node:"@C:\Users\ComputerName.txt" service where "name='wudfsvc'and started='true'" get name, started, status /format:htable > Services.html